# Parameter.value = ListBox .Item ...Delphi

Tags: database, delphi, listbox, items

I keep having this error about the datatype, but first I explain what i want to do:
I have a listBox containing some Items that I want to insert into my database so here's what i did:

```
For i:= 1 to ListBox.Count do
begin
  AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('PNumP').Value :=StrToInt(ListBox.Items[i]);
  AdoQuery1.ExecSQL;
end;
```

AdoQuery1 --> `Insert Into Table1 values(:PNumP)`
PNumP: Integer, size = 7 (Same as the column in Table1)

The error: `Could Not convert variant of type (UniCodeString) into type (Double).`

Comment: Have you tried to specify the column name in your insert statement (like `INSERT INTO Table1 (PNumP) VALUES (:PNumP)`) ?

Comment: What is actually in `ListBox.Items[i]`? Have you tried using proper SQL syntax (as TLama mentioned)? Also, based on the error message, the column is of type `double`, but you're using `StrToInt` - what type is the actual column?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
First of all, I have only one column in the table so i don't really need to specify it.
And the listBox contain Integers, list of integers...but I think that the operation ListBox.Items[i] give us String, that's why i did StrToInt. and as for the column type: it's Number(7)

Comment: Which part of the code raises the error?

Comment: Okey, I recreated the ADOQuery, and the table in the database, I don't know why; but it works now.